# Using toString() for set

Tags: java

I am using a set in my code which includes some integers in it. Somewhere in my code in need to have these numbers as a String so that a function could operate on them. (The function is permutation which gets a String as the input parameter.)

When my set is something like:

```
Set<Integer> U= new TreeSet<Integer>();
U.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
```

I need a string with the length of 9 which has these nine numbers in it. But by using

```
String str=U.toString();
```

str would be `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`  with the length of 27.

Is there anyway to store only the numbers into the string without the [ and , and spaces?

Comment: Why would you want to? If it's just a series of digits then how do you know what the actual values were? An array of 1 to 9 would give you the result 123456789, but so would an array containing three values: 123, 456 and 789. Can you guarantee that the array will only ever have single digit values? "Somewhere in my code in need to have these numbers as a String so that a function could operate on them." Sounds like that function needs to change, doesn't sound like it's well designed at all.

Comment: The other function gets a string and calculates is permutations. It is a pretty simple recursive function actually but the input must be String. The main purpose is to calculate the permutation of those digits.

Comment: So the function is built on the assumption that input is always a String formed from numbers of a single digit each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Set<Integer> U = new TreeSet<Integer>();
U.addAll(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9));

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(U.size());
for (int a : U)
    sb.append(a);

System.out.println(sb);
```

```
123456789
```

---

Java 8 approach:

```
Iterable<String> iter = U.stream().map(Object::toString)::iterator;
System.out.println(String.join("", iter));
```

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a subclass of TreeSet and override the toString() method as you want !

Answer (score 1):

@Override the toString in your extension class. A simple for loop should do it

Answer (score 1):

One way would be creating your own method.You can loop through the `Set`, and use a `StringBuilder` to construct the  `String`:

```
public String myToString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Integer i : U) {
        sb.append(i);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Another way would be overriding the `toString()` method. The implementation will be similar as the one above:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to implement it on your own:

```
public static String setToString(Set<Integer> set) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Integer i : set) {
        sb.append(i);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(U.toArray()));
```